# SignalR not connecting after updating to dotNet6

Tags: .net, xamarin, signalr, .net-6.0

I updated server to .NET 6 and kept old program and startup classes without change and everything is working fine but SignalR.
Since the update, xamarin client refuses to connect to hub, it stays in Connecting state.

Do i have to make any change to signalR on server side or is the problem somewhere else?

```
Namespace Hubs
{
    public class NotifyHub: Hub
    {

        public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
        {
            await base.OnConnectedAsync();
        }
    }
```

xamarin client:

```
namespace Clients
{
    class NotifyHubClient : INotifyHubClient
    {
        IDocumentService _ds;
        private HubConnection hubConnection;

        public async Task Connect()
        {
            if (hubConnection == null || hubConnection.State 
                == HubConnectionState.Disconnected)
            {
                InitConnection();
                await hubConnection.StartAsync();
            }
        }

        private void InitConnection()
        {
            _ds = ContainerLocator.Container.Resolve<IDocumentService>();
            hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
              .WithUrl("https://10.0.0.189:9001/hobosoft/notifier", options => {
                  options.HttpMessageHandlerFactory = (message) =>
                  {
                       if (message is HttpClientHandler clientHandler)
                           clientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback
                            +=(sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) 
                            => { return true; };
                       return message;
                  };
              })
             .WithAutomaticReconnect()
             .Build();
        }
```

Comment: SignalR works. It's impossible to guess why your project doesn't work though without any code.  What .NET Core version did you upgrade from? How did you set up SignalR ?

Comment: If SignalR didn't work. Blazor Server wouldn't work either. Blazor Server sends UI updates to a very small WebAssembly running on the browser to render them. If SignalR didn't work, no Blazor Server application would work either

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I was updating from .NET 5, my code is uploaded 
+ there is endpoints.MapHub<NotifyHub>("/hobosoft/notifier"); and services.AddSignalR(); in startup class

Comment: Post your code in the question. SignalR works. I'm using it in a .NET 6 web site for a year to send notifications to browser clients (I started with .NET 6 Preview 1). Have you checked the server logs? Are there any errors? Tried using Fiddler or a similar debugging proxy like Charles to see what is going on between client and server?

Comment: Create a *minimal* console app to test the client. Or perhaps a unit test. Right now you're trying to test too many things, and even your code contains some **extremely** suspicious things: `ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback`????????? If you have certificate issues, disabling validation won't fix them. It only means they'll bite you when .... you try to make a call. It also means HTTPS is essentially disabled. Instead of disabling validation during testing *trust the development certificate on your dev machine*

Comment: If certificate errors were covered up, what else may be wrong? Perhaps server exceptions are swallowed so the client never realizes the server crashed?

Comment: You can use `dotnet dev-certs https --trust` to trust the .NET Core development certificate. To trust a test site's certificate you can browse to it, click on the certificate warning icon at the left of the address bar and trust it. Or you can go to the Keychain and add it

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos So apparently i maybe found the problem. I was curious i tried everything and just could not make it work.. so i reseted to last git commit and it still did not work. Out of desperation tried running it in VS2019 and it works! 

apparently VS2022 have problem with xamarin SignalR and i am not the one with the same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found where the problem is. VS2022 have problem with xamarin SignalR, getting back to VS2019 solved the issue.

So that means I am unable update server to .NET 6, yet...